# 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'config' error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to run the following lines:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices("GPU")
for i in range(len(physical_devices)):
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[i], True)
```

I am trying to run this lines too:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
physical_devices = tf.test.gpu_device_name("GPU")
for i in range(len(physical_devices)):
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[i], True)
```

But the first method errors out like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_train.py", line 4, in <module>
    physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices("GPU")
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'config'
```

And the second method errors out like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_train.py", line 5, in <module>
    for i in range(len(tf.test.gpu_device_name("GPU"))):
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'test'
```

I am using Tensorflow 2.4.0 .Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

If anyone could help that would be great:)

Thank's for every help in advance:)

Comment: Your error is not reproducible in tf 2..4. It works just fine. Are you sure your tf version is that? Can you give some repro code of your issue?

Comment: Hey @M.Innat I've already fixed it:)

Answer (score -1):

I read that you already fixed it but since you didn't included it in your post here is the solution everyone else having this error: you need to change some modules from e.g. `tf.config.list_physical_devices("GPU")` to `tf.compat.v1.config.list_physical_devices("GPU")`. By adding ".compat.v1" you are ensuring backwards capability. You can use this code snippet for all other modules, that don't work.