# can't use GPU as tensorflow module has no attribute config

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu, attributeerror

I am new to machine learning. I have installed only (note: only) tensorflow 2.11.0 as shown below:

```
>pip show tensorflow
Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.11.0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: packages@tensorflow.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages
Requires: tensorflow-intel
Required-by:
```

Using the command:    `pip install tensorflow`

I haven't installed tensorflow-gpu for the following two reasons (as mentioned in many answers in stackoverflow):

- from tensorflow 2x I don't need to install tensorflow-gpu apparently.
- tensorflow-gpu requires an older version of keras which in turn is causing a conflict with some other features of tensorflow 2.11.0 which requires a more updated version of the same.

But, whenever I type the command:    `tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')`
I get an error message stating tensorflow has no attribute config. As shown below:

```
>>> tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'config'
```

I have a Windows 10 PC, with a very old graphics card: NVDIA GeForce GT 730, 2GB RAM and Python: 3.9

Can someone please help? Been stuck in this for a long time and it's so frustrating.

Edit: Even tried `tf.compat.v1.config.list_physical_devices("GPU")`
But still got the following errors:

```
>>> tf.compat.v1.config.list_physical_devices("GPU")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'compat'
>>>
```

Edit as asked by **@Kilian**, the output of `pip show tensorflow-estimator` is as follows:

```
>pip show tensorflow-estimator
Name: tensorflow-estimator
Version: 2.11.0
Summary: TensorFlow Estimator.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email:
License: Apache 2.0
Location: c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: tensorflow-intel
```

Edit as asked by **@Tfer3**, I am using the platform of both Anaconda and PyCharm.

Comment: Try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68022373/tensorflow-has-no-attribute-config-error

Comment: @Kilian I tried as you said but instead got the following errors can you please help: 
>>> tf.compat.v1.config.list_physical_devices("GPU")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'compat'
>>>

Comment: what do you get with:
pip show tensorflow-estimator

Comment: @Kilian as instructed by you, the output of pip show tensorflow-estimator is as follows:                                                                                                                     Name: tensorflow-estimator
Version: 2.11.0
Summary: TensorFlow Estimator.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email:
License: Apache 2.0
Location: c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: tensorflow-intel

Comment: @PiuMajumder, please let us know the platform(Pycharm or Anaconda) in which you are executing the above code. Thank you!

Comment: @Tfer3 I am using the platform of both pycharm and anaconda and both are giving me the same error.

Comment: Could you please try again and let us know if the issue still persists. Also ensure you are not using TF-gpu 2.11 as mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native) that "TensorFlow 2.10 was the last TensorFlow release that supported GPU on native-Windows."

Answer (score 1):

Please try using below code to verify GPU setup:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU').
```

which should `'[]'` return (as you have not setup GPU in your system)

Also ensure that you are not using TF-gpu 2.11 as mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native)

> TensorFlow 2.10 was the last TensorFlow release that supported GPU on
> native-Windows. Starting with TensorFlow 2.11, you will need to
> install TensorFlow in WSL2, or install tensorflow-cpu and, optionally,
> try the TensorFlow-DirectML-Plugin

Please follow this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) to install TensorFlow in conda environment. Let us know if the issue still persists.